# How do I compress rows in each column to get rid of the blank cells in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, data-wrangling

[This is the original Ter119high_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBWuJ.png)

```
new_columns = Ter119high_df['Specimen'].unique()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_columns)
print(new_df)

# Fill the new DataFrame with percentage values
for index, row in Ter119high_df.iterrows():
    specimen = row['Specimen'] 
    percent =row['Statistic']
    new_df.loc[index,specimen] = percent 
 
print(new_df)
new_df.to_csv("JupyterNotebookData/Ter119high_df_pivot_cleanv2.allmice.pivot.percent.csv")
```

This is new df is how I want it to look, but without all the blank space, how do I get rid of the empty cells?

[This is the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErU5e.png)

I tried to pivot my original data frame, but it did not get rid of the blank cells in the new data frame.
I want to have the new data frame with the Specimen names as headers and each of the percentages underneath, without blank cells.

Comment: The issue is related to using the `index` within your `new_df`. You don't seem to care about the index, you just want each column to have percent listings; The columns themselves are unrelated and therefore row1 of column A is unrelated to row1 of column B. Since the columns are unrelated, it may be easiest to create a dataframe for each Specimen and then join them together with something like `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, join='inner')`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from that `dataframe` and create a new `dataframe` out of it again like below:

```
d = {}

for col in new_columns:

    d[col] = new_df[col].value_counts().index.tolist()

print(d)

#creates a dataframe from dictionary

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').transpose()
```